# Would there be anything wrong with writing a program to pull Google Flights data?

Tags: united-states, internet, software

I live in Florida, U.S. and I would like to write a program (for personal use) which searches the Google Flights site for cheap flights. I am a beginner at programming so I have no idea if there are likely to be any issues with this. I tried looking through the terms of service and didn't find anything that I thought was prohibitive.

One thing I thought might be an issue is the number searches/minute, but I again didn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to the other answers, Googles Terms of Use state:

> Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide.

https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en

Google withdrew the Flights API in April 2018, leaving the website as the only public access for the data.

Given the wording in the general Google Terms of Service and the withdrawal of API support, it’s highly likely that scraping this data could be viewed as a breach of those terms as you are not accessing the web UI as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine. But make sure your program doesn't result in a too high ratio searches/minute that it "overwhelms" the server, since the host might perceive it as a DOS (Denial-Of-Service) attack.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's legal. Showing attribution might be a very good idea.

They will probably have an API (application programming interface) that you can use to gather data from Google Flights.

As for that, the concepts of a DoS attack would be furiously opening connections or sending more than requests can possibly be.

As for Vlggers, he says that it might "overwhelm the server". Google is less likely to be overwhelmed. It's got high connection speeds (and I mean more than even 10Gbps), along with fast processors (not just the average Intel) of a rather high clock speed.

Comment: Of course, Google has many more resources than the average server. But Helix's queries will reflect the same IP, whence higher ratios of queries per time unit are likelier to trigger alarms in whatever monitoring system Google may have in place.

Comment: As the worlds official "Test that my connection is working" site, I'm pretty sure Google is capable of handling a high volume of traffic.